# Display Out of Stock Products crash

Tags: inventory, out-of-stock, category-listing, not-showing

I have Issue Display Out of Stock Products when enabled.
Some link category menu are crashed.

Deprecated Functionality: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home/851015.cloudwaysapps.com/ftfwgauhdu/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php on line 222

I  have tried to disable every extension installed but the issue persist-

Can you help me please

Regards
Roberto[image]

Comment: This is deprecated error, you can fix it by running composer update, make sure to backup your code. can you tell what is your magento's version?

Comment: Which PHP version and Magento version are you using?

Comment: Seems like you have installed a version of PHP greater then the supported version of you r Magento version. You may  have to downgrade your PHP or upgrade your Magento.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates a deprecated functionality warning related to the preg_replace() function in the Zend/Db/Statement.php file. This warning is usually logged when Magento encounters code that uses deprecated features.

To resolve this issue, you can apply the following steps:

1. Check PHP Version: Ensure that your PHP version meets the requirements of your Magento version. Make sure you are using a supported PHP version.
2. Update Magento: If you are using an older version of Magento, consider updating to a more recent version. Newer versions often address bugs and compatibility issues.
3. Update Dependencies: Make sure your Magento installation has up-to-date dependencies. You can run the following command from your Magento root directory to update them:

> composer update

4. Review Customizations: If you have any custom code or extensions, review them for any usages of preg_replace() that might be passing null as the third parameter. Update the code to provide a valid subject to preg_replace(), either an array or a string.
5. Error Reporting: Enable error reporting and logging in Magento to get more detailed information about the error. You can do this by navigating to the Magento Admin Panel: Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enable Error Reporting and Enable Developer Mode.
6. Debugging: If the issue persists, you can debug the problem further by adding var_dump() or print_r() statements in the Statement.php file at line 222 to inspect the values being passed to preg_replace(). This can help identify the cause of the error.

Remember to clear the Magento cache after making any changes or updates.